# How to remove part of file names between periods?

Tags: rename, file-rename, batch-rename

I would like to rename many files in this format

```
abc.123.fits
abcd.1234.fits
efg.12.fits
```

to this format

```
abc.fits
abcd.fits
efg.fits
```

I tried the rename function, but since the part I'm trying to replace is not the same in all files, it did not work. I am using Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for f in *; do mv "$f" "${f%%.*}.${f##*.}"; done`
```

`${f%%.*}` removes everything after the first period, including the period. `${f##*.}` removes everything before the last period, including the period (i.e. it gets the file extension). Concatenating these two, with a period between them, gives you the desired result.

You can change the `*` to a more restrictive pattern such as `*.fits` if you don't want to rename all files in the current directory. The quotes around the parameters to `mv` are necessary if any filenames contain whitespace.

Many other variable substitution expressions are available in bash; see a reference such as [TLDP's Bash Parameter Substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) for more information.